# How to sort C++ array in ASC and DESC mode?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
array[0] = 18;
array[1] = -10;
array[2] = 2;
array[3] = 4;
array[4] = 6;
array[5] = -12;
array[6] = -8;
array[7] = -6;
array[8] = 4;
array[9] = 13;
```

how do I sort the array in asc/desc mode in C++?

Comment: You assigned the same position of your array each time. The final result of your array is 1-length with an entry of 13.

Comment: You didn't even populate the array, you repeatedly placed different values in the same location.

Comment: Pigben: my mistake. I have a habit of copy paste :p

Comment: @steven_desu What are you talking about?  ALL compliant compilers have std::sort.  If they don't, then they are not C++ compilers.

Comment: @steven: You should familiarize yourself with the C++ standard library, which *does* contain things like the `algorithm` header and  `std::sort()`. Any compiler claiming to compile C++ has to provide it.

Comment: Steven, you are quite mistaken. `algorithm` _is_ a standard header file. But universities don't teach standard headers, they teach you to do everything yourself.

Comment: @Computer Guru: Bjarne Stroustrup is a professor at Texas A&M university. In his freshmen course on programming using C++, he teaches standard containers and algorithms *right from the beginning* and defers arrays, pointers and other low-level details until much later (arrays and pointers are introduced on page 500 or something in Bjarne's latest book which is based on the university coursework). **That's the way modern C++ is supposed to be taught.** Use something first, and once you understand how to use it, *then* learn how it is implemented under the hood.

Comment: @cpp_best: populating the array can be done in an easier way: `int arr[] = {1,20, -1, 4,5,3 , -15};`

Comment: @FredOverflow: Interesting stuff! Thanks for sharing that, did not know. Just keep in mind that many universities teach C then a "data structures" course which uses C++ but isn't about C++, and that's generally why they leave out STL entirely.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To sort an array in ascending, use:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   // ...
   std::sort(array, array+n); // where n is the number of elements you want to sort
}
```

To sort it in descending, use

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>  

int main()
{
   // ...
   std::sort(array, array+n, std::greater<int>());
}
```

Comment: @steven_desu: What non-standard headers?

Comment: @steven: `algorithm` and `functional` **are** standard headers as defined by the international C++ standard (see 17.6.1.2 in the current draft). Hand-rolling your own sorting functions is a waste of time. It's error-prone and will most likely yield less efficient code. And what makes you think this is homework? Sometimes people just want to sort arrays and get on with their lives...

Comment: Or a simple lambda expression instead of include a whole functional header, which is also high performance because it is expanded out inline.

Comment: `std::greater<>()` works too (without specyifing template argument)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass custom comparison functor to the [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) function.

Answer (score 2):

Well first I'm hoping your array assignment was just an error when posting but all your numbers are being assigned to the same memory location. There's nothing to sort.

After that, you can use the [sort()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C%2B%2B%29) function. The example linked shows an easy method for using it. Note that there is a third parameter that's not being used that will specify how to compare the elements. By default if you don't specify the parameter it uses 'less-than' so you get an ascending order sort. Change this to specify 'greater-than' comparator to get a descending order sort.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int num[10]={18,-10,2,4,6,-12,-8,-6,13,-1};
        int temp;

        cout << "Ascending Sort : \n\n";

        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1; j<=10; j++)
                    {
                        if(num[i]>num[j])
                            {
                                temp=num[i];
                                num[i]=num[j];
                                num[j]=temp;
                            }
                    }
                cout << num[i] << "\n";
            }

        cout << "\nDescending Sort : \n\n";

        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1; j<=10; j++)
                    {
                        if(num[i]<num[j])
                            {
                                temp=num[j];
                                num[j]=num[i];
                                num[i]=temp;
                            }
                    }
                cout << num[i] << "\n";
            }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is broken as it accesses the array out of bounds.

Comment: Change all the i/j <= 10 to i/j < 10 to fix the out of bounds error.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can just swap the two variables in

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Change

```
bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (i<j); }
```

to

```
bool myfunction (int i,int j) { return (j<i); }
```

you can rename it to something else so that you have two comparison functions to use when the result needs to be ascending or descending.

If the function body has complicated expressions and involves `i` and `j` multiple times, then it is easier to swap the `i` and `j` in the parameter list instead of every `i` and `j` in the body:

```
bool myfunction (int j,int i) { return (i<j); }
```

The same goes for

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/