# Using sort() for descending instead of ascending C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the user given row or column of a 2d array. The code I have can sort in ascending order but not descending.

```
void sortArray(int arr[12][12], int index, int row)
{
   if (row == 0)
   {
       sort( arr[index] , arr[index] + 12);
   }
   else 
   {
       int tempArr[12];
       getColArr(arr, tempArr, index);
       sort(tempArr, tempArr + 12);
       for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       {
           arr[i][0] = tempArr[i];
       }
   }
}
```

How do I change it into descending?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008253/how-to-sort-c-array-in-asc-and-desc-mode

Answer (score 4):

You can use reverse iterators rbegin and rend, example:

```
int main()
{
    int vec[6] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    sort(rbegin(vec), rend(vec));

    for (const auto &i : vec) 
        cout << i << " ";
}
```

output: 6 5 4 3 2 1

Or you may use a lambda as the third argument to sort:

```
int vec[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
sort(vec, vec+6, [](int i, int j){return i>j;});
```

---

If you don't have a compiler that supports C++11 or C++14, you can create your own compare function and pass it as third argument to sort:

```
bool isGreater(int i, int j)
{
    return i > j;
}

int main()
{
    int vec[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    sort(vec, vec+6, isGreater);

    for (int i = 0; i != 6; ++i)
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
}
```

Output: 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::greater` as third parameter of `std::sort`

```
std::sort(begin(vec), end(vec),std::greater<int>());
```

FYI..when you use `std::sort` without third parameter, third parameter is defaulted with `std::less`.

Answer (score 1):

use 
    sort( arr[index] , arr[index] + 12, std::greater());

insted of

```
sort( arr[index] , arr[index] + 12);
```

For ascending sort;

```
//Sorts the elements in the range [first,last) into ascending order.
std::sort(tempArr, tempArr + 12); // default sort
```

For descending sort,

```
//you can use the comparator, the third argument in sort()
std::sort(tempArr, tempArr + 12, std::greater<int>());
```

for more, refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 0):

`sort` can only sort ascending... but you get to choose what ascending means.

If you tell `sort` that `x`, `y` is in ascending order if and only if `x > y`, then the sorted sequence will be in ascending order according to `operator >`, which is the same thing as descending order according to `operator <`.

You could write your own custom functor to do this or use a lambda, but the standard library already has a functor for this purpose:

```
using std::sort;
sort(begin(arr), end(arr), std::greater<int>());
```

In C++14, you should use `std::greater<>` instead of `std::greater<int>`.