# c++ sort(ascending,descending) integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So i'm new in C++ and i'm trying some beginner exercises here is the problem : i have to order an integer array in ascending and descending order but every time i try the ascending order there is a 0 appearing out of nowhere inside my array replacing a previous array integer. This is happening only when i use the "ascending order" option. I've tried rearranging the numbers inside the array and changing them but the same thing happens i really can't figure out the problem.I would appreciate some help and i hope my question is not dumb and waste your time.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int i,y,choice,temp,am[5]={8,6,10,7,9};

cout<<"Choice 1 : Descending\nChoice 2 : Ascending\n";
cin>>choice;

if(choice==1)
{
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        y=i+1;
        while(y<5)
        {
            while(am[i]<am[y])
            {
                temp=am[i];
                am[i]=am[y];
                am[y]=temp;
                y++;
            }
            y++;
        }
    }
}
else if(choice==2)
{
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        y=i+1;
        while(y<5)
        {
            while(am[i]>am[y])
            {
                temp=am[i];
                am[i]=am[y];
                am[y]=temp;
                y++;
            }
            y++;
        }
    }
}
else
    cout<<"Error\n";

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    cout<<"am[i]:"<<am[i]<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

[here is what i see in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkspf.png)

Comment: Is this a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4008266/5847906)? (if you can use c++11)

Comment: `std::sort(..., std::less<int>{})`, `std::sort(..., std::greater<int>{})` and your'e done.

Comment: You might run out of bounce in the inner while `while(am[i]>am[y])`. It is not checking `y < 5`. And I guess you just get random numbers in there.

Comment: `while(am[i]<am[y])` inside this loop you increment `y` with nothing to stop `y` going past the end of the array.  This might not be the problem you are having.  I would suggest learning how to use your debugger, this program is perfect for this.

Comment: *i have to order an integer array in ascending and descending order* -- Can you name the type of sort algorithm you're trying to implement?  If you can't name it, start there first before you write a single line of code.  Even the bad sorting algorithms (like *bubble sort*) are named.

Comment: [Compiler to the rescue!](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fkXKEJRfO60D98eS) Learn to know your tools. :)

Comment: The great thing about C++ is the fact that standard library already has a large algorithms library. Learning to use them instead of rolling your own is much more productive most of the time. Plus you can always see their implementation.

Comment: No it isn't ,i'm trying to figure out my way of ordering without using what C++ offers for sorting.

Comment: It is working fine for me

Comment: @Nick -- Study the way sorts are done algorithmically.  There are a few of them.  Then implement them in code.  Trying to do sorting with "off-the-cuff" coding doesn't usually work.

Comment: @sanjay Really? So i guess its has to do with my compiler or the version and product i'm using to write the code? I don't really know by the way i'm using DEV C++ should i change IDE ?

Comment: @Nick -- It is not the compiler.  Your code is just plain wrong.  There is no way a C++ compiler that is used by thousands of programmers all over the world would have trouble with such simple code.

Comment: I would guess it has to do with the out of bounds iteration which was mentioned before. You should use a debugger and go with your program step-by-step. You will see the error there (and actually learn to use a debugger)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah i guess you are right but you know i'm doing it to exercise and learn some things or two by doing it, will i even be able to understand what the algorithm doing if i cant just make something like this work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie plain wrong ?! oh god okay now im embarrassed :D

Comment: @Hayt thanks i will try it !

Comment: @Nick -- You don't need to know any computer language to understand an algorithm, as all an algorithm does is describe a series of steps to reach the goal.  [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie May i ask a last question? So what goes first ? Learning the basics of the language and then proceed to learn some useful algorithms and libraries or everything in the same time ? Like at this point should i try to learn how the algorithm of sorting works and then try to use it for this exersice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Selection Sort. Your program has 4 errors. Use '**if**' instead of **while**.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,y,choice,temp,am[5]={8,6,10,7,9};

    cout<<"Choice 1 : Descending\nChoice 2 : Ascending\n";
    cin>>choice;

    if(choice==1)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            y=i+1;
            while(y<5)
            {
                if(am[i]<am[y])    //Correction1
                {
                    temp=am[i];
                    am[i]=am[y];
                    am[y]=temp;
                    //y++;         //Correction2
                }
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            y=i+1;
            while(y<5)
            {
                if(am[i]>am[y])      //Correction3
                {
                    temp=am[i];
                    am[i]=am[y];
                    am[y]=temp;     
                    //y++;          //Correction4
                }
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"Error\n";

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<"am[i]:"<<am[i]<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It really worked i can't believe it was that simple thanks a lot ! And thanks everyone for every suggestion and advice  .

Answer (score 0):

The Reason for the failure.

Changes of your algorithm in each iteration:

```
am[0]:6
am[1]:8
am[2]:10
am[3]:7
am[4]:9

am[0]:6
am[1]:7
am[2]:10
am[3]:8
am[4]:9

am[0]:6
am[1]:7
am[2]:8
am[3]:10
am[4]:9

am[0]:6
am[1]:7
am[2]:8
am[3]:9
am[4]:10
am[0]:6
am[1]:7
am[2]:8
am[3]:0
am[4]:10

am[i]:6
am[i]:7
am[i]:8
am[i]:0
am[i]:10
```

Now hope you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this:

```
while(am[i]>am[y])
{
   temp=am[i];
   am[i]=am[y];
   am[y]=temp;
   y++;
}
```

might cause problems in general. I mean, you increment `y`, but don't check if it's less than the array length (`5` in this case), so I think that for some cases it would start comparing and swapping with elements from beyond the array. I'm amazed that you didn't get segfault yet.
This problem appears to be in the both of the options (ascending and descending).

What I'd dp with that would be changing this `while` loop with and `if` statement, and removing `y++` from it

```
if(am[i]>am[y])
{
   temp=am[i];
   am[i]=am[y];
   am[y]=temp;
}
```

That way the parent while loop still handles incrementing `y` and checking if it's less than `5` but we can't address something out of the array.
I'm not sure if it will solve the problem, although that 0 appears out of nowhere, so it's most probably from somewhere beyond the array, and since it appears somewhere near the end of the sorting it doesn't go down, because your algorithm assumes (and correctly btw) that all previous elements are already sorted.

I'd suggest you implementing bubble sort, since it's easy to understand and implement, and holds some potential for optimization (I optimized it so hard that it's worst case was faster than merge sort... don't know why though).

Comment: "might cause problems in general. I mean, you increment y, but don't check if it's less than the array length (5 in this case), so I think that for some cases it would start comparing and swapping with elements from beyond the array. "
Yes that make sense i guess thanks a lot !