# C++ - Sort array in descending order not working

Tags: c++, sorting

```
int array[6] = {5, 10, 2, 5, 4, 4}
std::sort(array, array + (sizeof array / sizeof array[0]), std::greater<int>());
```

I am trying to sort the above array in descending order, but when I run the sort function on it I am getting the following:

```
{10, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: The problem was with surrounding code I had. The code posted here is actually correct.. Sorry.

Comment: [norepro](https://ideone.com/XLlpt1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort C++ array in ASC and DESC mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008253/how-to-sort-c-array-in-asc-and-desc-mode)

Comment: It works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example of the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), what you have should work:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main (void) {
  int array[6] = {5, 10, 2, 5, 4, 4};
  std::sort(array, array + (sizeof array / sizeof array[0]), std::greater<int>());

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 10 5 5 4 4 2

As you can see, this is the same as your code. See it yourself in the <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jPHYsLawF9EafXyk)</kbd>.