# Take some Random numbers as input and print the numbers in descending order

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int print_max(int a, int b);
main()
{
    int low=0,max,min;
    int num[5];
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
    cout<<"Plz Enter the number "<<endl;
    cin>>num[i];
    low=print_max(num[i],low); 
    max=print_max(num[i],low);

    }
    cout<<max;
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        if(max>num[i])
        min=num[i];
        cout<<min;
    }
}
int print_max(int a,int b)
{
    int max;
    if (a>b)
    {max=a;
    return max;}
    else
    {
    max=b;
    return max;
    }
}
```

I want to sort some random numbers which I am given as input and sort them in descending order. The "low" parameter will save the greater number and then "max" will compare all the values with "low" and will save the greater value. Then, I added the `if` condition in the loop so that it will compare all the values of input with "max" and find the minimum values. The output of the program is not the numbers in descending orders. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008253/how-to-sort-c-array-in-asc-and-desc-mode

Comment: The first and second `for-loop`s in your `main` results to a `segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your program. You can see this example to understand your mistakes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 5;
    int low = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
    int num[N] = {0};
    for(auto i = 0U; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Plz Enter the number " << endl;
        cin >> num[i];
        if(num[i] < low)
            low = num[i];
        if(num[i] > max)
            max = num[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "max: " << max << endl;
    cout << "min: " << low << endl << endl;

    std::sort(num, num + N, [](int i, int j){return i > j;});
    for(auto i = 0U; i < N; i++)
        cout << num[i] << " ";
}
```

Some of your errors:

- in c/c++ array elements are numbered from 0 to N-1, for example

  ```
  int a[5]; // valid elements are a[0]...a[4]
  ```
- in *print_max* you don't need variable '*max*':

  ```
  int print_max(int a,int b)
  {
      if(a > b)
          return a;
      else
          return b;
  }
  ```
- as seen in example above, you don't need _print_max_ at all.
- variable initialization is a good practice:

  ```
      int low = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
      int num[N] = {0};
  ```

You can use some kind of BubbleSort instead *std::sort* if you need:

```
void sort(int *num, unsigned int size)
{
    for(auto i = 0U; i < size-1; i++)
        for(auto j = 0U; j < size-i; j++)
            if(num[j] < num[j + 1])
            {
                auto tmp = num[j];
                num[j] = num[j + 1];
                num[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
}
```