# How to sort a standard array in descending order - C++ 11

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11

There are resources out there for sorting an array in descending order:

https://www.includehelp.com/stl/sort-an-array-in-descending-order-using-sort-function.aspx

[How to sort C++ array in ASC and DESC mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008253/how-to-sort-c-array-in-asc-and-desc-mode)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-c-stl/

but none address the question of doing this for a `std::array` and not primitive `int myArr[]` type.

I have a code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    array<int, 5> myArray = {30, 22, 100, 6, 0};

    for(int item : myArray){
        cout << item << endl;
    }

    sort(myArray.begin(), myArray.end());

    cout << "NOW, SORTED: " << endl;

    for (int otheritem: myArray){
        cout << otheritem << endl;
    }

}
```

Which produces:

```
30
22
100
6
0
NOW, SORTED:
0
6
22
30
100
```

However, I am trying to produce this output:

```
100
30
22
6
0
```

By sorting the array in descending order. I have tried following the tips from the SO post above:

```
sort(myArray, myArray.size()+n, greater<int>());
```

But that generates error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "sort" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (std::array<int, 5ULL>, unsigned long long, std::greater<int>)
```

How can I sort `standard array` of `int` in descending order?

Comment: `std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), std::greator<int>())`. That works whether `myArray` is a `std::vector`, `std::array`, or a real array type (e.g. `int[5]`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike the raw arrays, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) won't convert to pointer implicitly (even you can get the pointer explicitly from [`std::array::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data)), you should use `begin()` and `end()`, which are commonly used to get iterators from STL containers. e.g.

```
sort(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), greater<int>());
```

or

```
sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), greater<int>());
```

PS: The latter works with raw arrays too.

Comment: Thank you. I could not find resources for sorting in descending order with non-raw array type.

Comment: @JerryM. What you need is to understand what iterators are and how to get the beginning and ending iterator for the type of container you're working with.